# Click to call from app to OpenVBX

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, twilio, openvbx

I am trying to POST two pieces of data from an external webapp to OpenVBX.

```
calltonum:(phone number in format +12345678902)
callfromnum:(phone number in format +12345678902)
```

Once the data is in the app I am trying to use this feature:
http://www.openvbx.org/docs/browserphone/api/

```
OpenVBX.clientDial({
    'to': calltonum,
    'callerid': callfromnum
});
```

I have verified this Javascript function works from a plugin, but havent been able to successfully post the data to a plugin yet. I was originally afraid I would run into authentication issues, but quickly found if I have an open session already and post data directly to a function inside a custom controller with a class that extends the `User_Controller`... It receives the post data and passes it to the view just fine.

Right now, my issue is that when I load the view it populates great with all the CSS and Javascript and data view-able on the screen but <strike>then the page requests '/' to load which redirects the browser to /messages/inbox.</strike> I am also getting a js error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ dosomethingplease:116
```

When trying to use the browserphone api leading me to believe jquery hasnt been loaded in the template.

Here is the code I currently have:

**dialbrowser.php created in /controllers**

```
<?php 

class dialbrowserException extends Exception {}

class dialbrowser extends User_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();  
}
public function index()
{
    return $this->dosomethingplease();
}
public function dosomethingplease()
{
    $data = $this->init_view_data();
    $this->template->add_js('assets/j/plugins/call-and-sms-dialogs.js');
    $this->template->add_js('assets/j/frameworks/jquery-1.6.2.min.js');
    $data = array('calltonum' => $this->input->post('calltonum'), 'callfromnum' => $this->input->post('callfromnum'));

    $this->respond('title','dialnow', $data);
}    
}

?>
```

**dialnow.php created in /views**

```
<div class="vbx-content-main">

<div class="vbx-content-menu vbx-content-menu-top">
    <h2 class="vbx-content-heading">Test-a-roo</h2>
</div><!-- .vbx-content-menu -->

<div class="vbx-content-container">
    <div class="vbx-content-section">
        <div class="vbx-form">
            <h3>Receipt of Number passed:</h3>
                <div>
                    And here we made it the whole way.... didnt think we could do it huh? 
                    <?php 
                    echo "lets do this for sanity's sake... to: ".$calltonum." and from: ".$callfromnum." ...see no issues with the data!";
                    $html = "<script> $('document').ready(function(){OpenVBX.clientDial({'to': '".$calltonum."', 'callerid': '".$callfromnum."'});}); </script>";
                    echo $html;
                    ?>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .vbx-content-section -->
</div><!-- .vbx-content-container -->

</div><!-- .vbx-content-main -->
```

and I can currently post to /dialbrowser/index or /dialbrowser/dosomethingplease successfully, and the data populates in the view.

What I don't understand is, <strike>why is it redirecting? And,</strike> since I am extending the `User_Controller` shouldnt all the critical jquery/javascript already be loaded successfully?

**UPDATE**: I changed `$route['dialbrowser'] = "dialbrowser";` in `/config/routes.php`. It doesnt redirect at the controller level now! Now I can see the left menu is not there, the call button has no functionality, and the previous javascript error still persists.

Comment: OpenVBX is written in Codeigniter.. I had a hell of a time modifying it myself until I learned CI.. if you're planning on doing much development with it, it's probably worth it to do a tutorial on CI..

Comment: Yeah I tagged codeigniter on this post because I was hoping some codeigniter fans could tell me if I am missing something. I have watched some videos but dont really have the time or interest to learn everything about CI- especially since its dated some v.1.7 I believe is what OpenVBX is on. @Pamblam if you want to add OpenVBX tag to this post for me that would be very nice of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? There's a concept plugin to add click to call to Openvbx, but you need to modify a few lines to disable security on posting to plug-ins without authorization.  https://github.com/twilio/OpenVBX/wiki/Plugin-Click-to-Flow

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the document ready is not working in plugin page. You should try **window.onload** instead of **$('document').ready**
So the line will be:

```
$html = "<script> window.onload=function(){OpenVBX.clientDial({'to': '".$calltonum."', 'callerid': '".$callfromnum."'});}; </script>";
```